# React Router is Not Matching Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm not able to get my routes to work as expected.  I'm suspecting it's because I have my App.js setup with Routes that are working fine.  But then, within one of those Routes, I want that page to also have it's own Routes.  Those are the ones I cannot get to work. I cannot figure where I've gone wrong.

This is my App.js which works perfectly:

```
const App = () => {
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Tools} />
            <Route exact path="/audit" component={Audit} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But then, if you go to the "Audit" component, that is a page, which has it's own menu to display different components.  Here is that code:

```
const Audit = () => { 

        return (
          <div>
            <NavTabs />
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/general" component={General} />
                <Route exact path="/culture" component={Culture} />
                <Route exact path="/performance" component={Performance} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        );
}

export default Audit;
```

When I click on any of these, I just get the "NoMatch" component that my App.js calls for.

This is my NavBar from the Audit component if it helps:

```
class NavTabs extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <Nav fill variant="tabs" defaultActiveKey="/general">
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/general">General</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/culture" eventKey="link-1">
                Culture
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/performance" eventKey="link-2">
                Performance
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        );
    }
};

export default NavTabs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to wrap the `<BrowserRouter>` once, usually with the `app.js` And your nested routes in `<Audit>` should be `path='/audit/general'` Try if that works.
I just noticed you had two exact path in app.js Only one should exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not.  The correct path shows in the browser address bar, but it still goes to my "NoMatch" page.

Comment: Actually, that did it.  I removed all the "exact" and it started working.  I guess I don't really understand how exact works and I need to look that up.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: yes you should learn how it works. But it was confusing to me too, so simply put, you will put it to the route that you always want to render first.